A basic riddle in the form of a poem
I'd forgotten my roots after the century-long lie,
As a shameless daydreamer in Mars' pink sky.
After birthing triplets, my ambitions fulfilled,
I never looked back on those days near nil.
What happened to me, and who am I?

Solution:

 I am the number 2, who has been written as 100 in base $\sqrt{2}$. (To convert to base $\sqrt{2}$, we calculate $1\cdot\sqrt{2}^2 + 0\cdot\sqrt{2}^1 + 0\cdot\sqrt{2}^0$)


Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! It looks like you've answered your own riddle within ten minutes of posting it. The usual approach here is to let other people work out the answer, (maybe start adding hints if no-one gets it after a few days).
